# snakemake: define parameter based on sample name or other input

Tags: snakemake

Thank you in advance for all of your help on here!
I have a snakemake file defining steps for processing short-read data, mapping, and variant calling. I'm hoping to use different reference sequences for different samples and I'm wondering how you would recommend defining the reference based on an input sample name?

For example, I defined my run and sample names using wildcards. I hope to define my ref based on the sample (or run) name, so that samples are mapped to the correct reference. My rule map_reads is below.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
# Define samples: 
RUNS, SAMPLES = glob_wildcards("/xyz/{run}/{samp}_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz")
sample_dict  = dict(zip(SAMPLES,RUNS))
print("runs are: ", RUNS)
print("samples are: ", SAMPLES)

# Map reads.
rule map_reads:
  input:
    ref_path='/xyz/refs/{ref}.fasta',
    kr1='process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_kr_1.fq.gz',
    kr2='process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_kr_2.fq.gz'
  output:
    bam='process/bams/{run}_{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_rg_sorted.bam'
  params:
    mapper='{mapper}'
  log:
    'process/bams/{run}_{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_map.log'
  threads: 8
  shell:
    "/xyz/scripts/map_reads.sh {input.ref_path} {params.mapper} {input.kr1} {input.kr2} {output.bam} &>> {log}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a file relating your samples and reference genome and then read that into a dictionary (or pandas dataframe).

The dictionary/dataframe can then be accessed in the input to determine the right reference for the given sample.

Here is a dictionary example.

Given a tab separated file *samples.txt* relating sample to reference like so:

```
sample_A   ref_A
sample_B   ref_B
sample_C   ref_C
```

Then, using a lambda function, we can access the wildcards object in the input and use the samp wildcard to find the corresponding reference in our dictionary.

```
# Define samples: 
RUNS, SAMPLES = glob_wildcards("/xyz/{run}/{samp}_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz")
sample_dict  = dict(zip(SAMPLES,RUNS))
print("runs are: ", RUNS)
print("samples are: ", SAMPLES)

# Read samples.txt into dictionary.
sample_to_ref = {}
with open("samples.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split("\t")
        sample_to_ref[line[0]] = line[1]  # sample_to_ref[sample] = reference

# Map reads.
rule map_reads:
  input:
    ref_path= lambda wildcards: expand('/xyz/refs/{ref}.fasta', ref=sample_to_ref[wildcards.samp]),  # lambda allows access to wildcards, to then access dictionary.
    kr1='process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_kr_1.fq.gz',
    kr2='process/trim/{run}_{samp}_trim_kr_2.fq.gz'
  output:
    bam='process/bams/{run}_{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_rg_sorted.bam'
  params:
    mapper='{mapper}'
  log:
    'process/bams/{run}_{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_map.log'
  threads: 8
  shell:
    "/xyz/scripts/map_reads.sh {input.ref_path} {params.mapper} {input.kr1} {input.kr2} {output.bam} &>> {log}"
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!